# I want to filter listbox items with linq . But I get an error

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code 
Listbox1 = input, Listbox2 = output, Filter = my filter textbox

```
    private void filter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         listBox2.DataSource = from Name in listBox1.Items
             .Cast<String>()
             .ToList()
             where Name.StartsWith(Filter.Text)
             select Name;
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHArgument);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Comment: Give the exception message in stead of a general link. The message should show specific information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the error but looking at your code. I think you are missing to wrap the whole query in ToList

```
listBox2.DataSource = (from Name in listBox1.Items.Cast<String>() where Name.StartsWith(Filter.Text) select Name).ToList();
```

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes  First ToList is actually not needed...Cast is anyway going to return IEnumerable<string> which is enough to use in Linq query. I will update it in answer too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly where your problem is; however, you have a strange mix of LINQ query syntax and extension method syntax. And also, since you are executing a where clause after converting to list, the result will be an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Assuming that your combobox items are *strings*, I would do this:

```
listBox2.DataSource = listBox1.Items
    .Cast<string>()
    .Where(s => s.StartsWith(Filter.Text))
    .ToList();
```

If your combobox contains *something else* and you want to insert these objects in the other listbox:

```
listBox2.DataSource = listBox1.Items
    .Cast<SomethingElse>()
    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(Filter.Text))
    .ToList();
```

Or if you want to insert only the *names* contained in these objects:

```
listBox2.DataSource = listBox1.Items
    .Cast<SomethingElse>()
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .Where(n => n.StartsWith(Filter.Text))
    .ToList();
```

In my view, the LINQ query syntax is not of great help here and merely adds  complexity. That's why I stick to the extension method syntax.